# How to add dynamic arguments in slash commands [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

## The Question

I'm trying to make a command that shows you the schedule of your class, for that, the user first introduces as an argument its degree and then the class, but every degree has a different number of classes, so I can't show a generic list for all the degrees.

The actual code:

```py
class Ciclos(enum.Enum):
    ASIX = 1
    DAM = 2


class ASIX(enum.Enum):
    _1A = 1
    _1B = 2
    _1C = 3
    _2A = 4
    _2B = 5


class DAM(enum.Enum):
    _1A = 1
    _2A = 2
    _2B = 3

@bot.tree.command(name="schedule", description="Shows the schedule of the selected class")
@app_commands.describe(ciclo="Choose your degree")
@app_commands.describe(clase="Choose your class")
async def schedule(interaction: discord.Interaction, ciclo: Ciclos, clase: Ciclos.name):
await interaction.response.send_message(file=discord.File(f'Media/schedules/schedule{ciclo.name}{clase.name}.png'))
```

This code doesn't work, but I hope it serves to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. The problematic part is on the function parameters, specifically on `clase: Ciclos.name`, I don't know how to make it depend on what the user chooses on `ciclo: Ciclos`.

## What I've tried

I've tried to put these expressions:

`clase: {Ciclos.name}`
I get -> AtributeError: name

`clase: Ciclos.name`
I get -> AtributeError: name

`clase: ciclo`
I get -> NameError: name 'ciclo' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Ciclos'?
No, I didn't mean that.

## Expected behavior

The expected result is this:
[class ASIX example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/491V5.png)
[class DAM example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkeN1.png)

In order to send the schedule image corresponding to each class:

```py
await interaction.response.send_message(file=discord.File(f'Media/schedules/schedule{ciclo.name}{clase.name}.png'))
```

So I get file names like:
"scheduleASIX_1A"
"scheduleDAM_2A"

Comment: This isn't possible from a Discord side of things. The choices have to be known beforehand & can't dynamically change based on other values (also - you can fill them in in any order, so that wouldn't even work). You'll have to do it some other way. You can't refer to the current value of that argument as the type of the Choice.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's why I couldn't find any example of that, because it's not possible. I'll try to find another way to do it. I would mark your answer as the most correct one, but it's a comment.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible from a Discord side of things. The choices have to be known beforehand and synced, so they can't dynamically change based on other values (also - you can fill them in in any order, so that wouldn't even work).

You'll have to do it some other way. You can't refer to the current value of that argument as the type of the Choice.

One option could be to use Views with Select menus, for example. A more hybrid approach could be to have a slash command with Choices, and let that one answer with a Select menu for the specific options they can choose depending on their argument. There's an example for Select menus: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/dropdown.py

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I don't think dynamic choises are build into the discord api, but I usually use the following to add choises to a Slash command, maybee it can help you.

```
@app_commands.choices(
ciclo=[
    app_commands.Choice(name="ASIX", value="ASIX"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="DAM", value="DAM")
    ],
clase=[app_commands.Choice(name="A1", value="A1")])
```

I modified it to fit your example a bit to fit your example, but as said, as far as I know there is no way to make dynamic choices with the slash commands.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your example is adding more than one argument to the command, not a dynamic argument, but your first paragraph answered my question. It is not possible to make dynamic choices. I'll mark your answer as the one that solved the problem.